# Detect existing Devise::Rememberable user before login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, devise

Is it possible, upon return to a non-Devise page, to determine if the user is a rememberable user (i.e. has had a previous session and has checked "remember me")?

Looking into the Rememberable code, it appears it would be possible by examining signed cookies:

```
cookies.signed[remember_key(resource, scope)] = remember_cookie_values(resource)
```

but when examining this upon return to the site, the cookie is empty

Comment: Looking into the Rememberable code, it appears it would be possible by examining signed cookies: `cookies.signed[remember_key(resource, scope)] = remember_cookie_values(resource)` but when examining this upon return to the site, the cookie is empty.

Comment: One option...

`Warden::Manager.after_set_user do |user, auth, opts|   
  scope = opts[:scope]   
  auth.cookies.permanent["rememberable"] = <rememberable_status>   
end  
`